# Proof that the Kronecker product is the equivalent of a double matrix multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra

[Here is my reference.](http://www.pyrunner.com/weblog/2016/05/26/compressed-sensing-python/)

Quoting:

> If [a] $\text{vec}(X)$  is the vector operator that stacks columns of $X$ on top of each other, then:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \text{vec}(D_mXD_n^\top) & = (D_n \otimes D_m) \text{vec}(X)
> \end{align}$$

This trick allows unfolding a matrix $X$ into a long $\text{vec}(X),$ treating it like such as it gets mutiplied on the left by the Kronecker product of the two matrices that are supposed to modify $X$ as though they were a single matrix.

But is there an elegant linear algebra proof to this equality, which I see it does work very well on numerical computaions?

Comment: The RHS should be $(D_{\color{red}{m}}\otimes D_{\color{red}{n}})\operatorname{vec}(X)$.

Comment: @user1551 I made the correction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not elegant but a direct proof. Fix some orthonormal $\{e_i\}$ and write
$$
X = \sum_{ij} a_{ij} e_{i} e_{j}^*,
$$
where $e_{i}e_{j}^*$ is the *outer product* of the basis elements $e_{i}$ and $e_{j}$. That is $e_{i}e_{j}^*$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $(i,j)$ element and 0 elsewhere. Write the other matrices in a similar way then you can write
$$
AXB^T = \sum_{ijkl} a_{ij} x_{jk} b_{lk} e_{i} e_{l}^*.
$$
Note that the $\mathrm{vec}$ operation is linear and it acts on $e_{i}e_{j}^*$ as $\mathrm{vec}(e_{i}e_{j}^*) = e_{i} \otimes e_j$. Therefore,
$$
\mathrm{vec}(AXB^T) = \sum_{ijkl} a_{ij} x_{jk} b_{lk} e_{i} \otimes e_{l}.
$$

Then we can simply just calculate the RHS also by writing
$$
A \otimes B = \sum_{ijkl} a_{ij} b_{kl} e_{i}e_{j}^* \otimes e_{k}e_{l}^*
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{vec}(X) = \sum_{mn} x_{mn}  e_{m} \otimes e_n
$$
which gives
$$
\sum_{ijkl} a_{ij}b_{kl}x_{jl} e_{i} \otimes e_{k}
$$
which is exactly what we had before up to relabelling $k \leftrightarrow l$.

Comment: Thank you very much!